# Show the popup, not just the icon, for a pageAction?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I can use [setPopup()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction/setPopup) to control the content, and [show()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction/show) to make the *icon* for my WebExtension's `pageAction` appear programmatically for a given tab.  But I want the content of the popup itself to become visible at a time that my (background) script chooses.

Comment: You will need to open a new tab or window.

Comment: There is no way to open an *actual* `pageAction` or `browserAction` popup, but [you can fake it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40296092/3773011). I need to move the code in that answer into an answer specifically about programmatically opening a Chrome extension/Firefox WebExtension popup. I'll do so in a bit. I'm working on something else at the moment.