# Force extension to not close after switching tab or clicking on a page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my popup.html to stay always on top (unless I close it with my button with function window.close). I need to switch tabs without having to reopen my extension.

Comment: Can't do. You'll have to create a separate window via chrome.windows.create.

Comment: As wOxxOm has said, it's not possible to do this with an *actual* `browser_action`/`page_action` popup. You can create a pseudo-popup, which is actually a separately window. There's some code to do that in my answer to [How to create a global hotkey for opening the "browserAction" popup in Firefox (WebExtensions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40296092). You will need to modify the code a bit as it's specifically intended to mimic the behavior of an actual popup. While that answer mentions WebExtensions multiple times, the base code was also tested in Chrome.